# Correctly use UTF-8 chars as hash keys

Tags: ruby, hash, utf-8

Following code reads content from UTF-8 file, counts letters in the each string (using hash) and outputs result to another file.

The problem is that each letter in hash are represented as utf-8 code, not symbol.

How correctly use symbols, not their utf-8 code in the hash?

```
#encoding=utf-8
#Encoding.filesystem = "UTF-8"
length = 0

letters = Hash.new(0)

File.open("hist_1.txt", "r:UTF-8") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp
    line.chars.each do |l|
      l = l.encode("Windows-1251", "UTF-8")
      letters[l] += 1 
    end
    end
  end
end

a = letters.sort
#
#p a
puts a
File.open("results.txt", "w:UTF-8") { |file| file.write a }
```

Comment: Would you please share an example of input file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/azjhhmbwy7vzjld/hist_1.txt?dl=0
Can't attach file to the post (

Comment: Copy-paste to dropbox obviously makes the file utf-encoded, thus makes no sense. Anyway, whether you are concerned that input is `cp1251`, why are you opening it as `utf-8`?

Comment: File content is in utf-8. And i want to read utf-8 content/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The problem is that each letter in hash are represented as utf-8 code, not symbol", can you share an example?  I wonder if it's just that your terminal isn't showing utf8 properly?

Comment: If your data is already in utf8, then calling `l = l.encode("Windows-1251", "UTF-8")` will do nothing but corrupt it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that while your desired output is about letters, you should not use neither `chars`, nor `codepoints`:

```
content = File.read("hist_1.txt", encoding: "UTF-8") # read the whole file
#       ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ split to letters
content.split(//).inject(Hash.new(0)) do |memo, cp|
  memo[cp] += 1
  memo
end
#⇒ {"В"=>1, "о"=>5, "т"=>5, " "=>9, "п"=>4, "э"=>1, ...}
```

Now you probably want to call `downcase` on hash key and get rid of spaces and punctuation.

Comment: File.read("hist_1.txt", "r:UTF-8") - won't work, you have to use File.read("hist_1.txt", encoding: "UTF-8"). And the last of the code is more elegant, than mine, but has the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for wrong syntax for `File#read`, I fixed it. For the rest: if you are sure the file is in UTF-8, the code above works. And vice versa, it it does not work, it means you have a file in `cp1251`, try _to read it that way_.